# How is 'Jared' greater than 'Brittany'?

Tags: string, binary-tree, lexicographic

I'm looking in my book, and it doesn't explain it. Its telling me what a binary search tree is and it decided to use strings.

```
         Jared
        /     \
 Brittany      Megan
 /      \        /   \
Brett  Doug     Jim  Whitney
```

So supposedly, a node is greater than its left subtree and lesser than its right subtree. How is Jared greater than Brittany?

Comment: Brittany is before Jared in the dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a dictionary, the word "Jared" would come after "Brittany".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: Wow, it was so obvious. I was going through Unicodes, and all these different things. I'm such a moron.

Answer (score 1):

Using default string comparison rules, characters with larger integer codes makes string "larger" i.e. 'J' > 'B'. However there is lot of nuances in real life :)